Put The Chartjs on Canvas using Nextjs
I have the problem when using chart on the image canvas, the issue is that the chart does not show/appear on the image canvas.
const drawCanvas = (canvasWidth, canvasHeight) => {
      const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

      canvas.width = canvasWidth * dpr;
      canvas.height = canvasHeight * dpr;
      ctx.scale(dpr, dpr);

      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      const imgAspectRatio = bgImage.width / bgImage.height;
      const canvasAspectRatio = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;

      let imgWidth, imgHeight;
      if (canvasAspectRatio > imgAspectRatio) {
        imgHeight = canvasHeight;
        imgWidth = imgHeight * imgAspectRatio;
      } else {
        imgWidth = canvasWidth;
        imgHeight = imgWidth / imgAspectRatio;
      }

      const xOffset = (canvasWidth - imgWidth) / 2;
      const yOffset = (canvasHeight - imgHeight) / 2;

      ctx.drawImage(bgImage, xOffset, yOffset, imgWidth, imgHeight);

      // Function for showing the chart
      lineChart(xOffset, yOffset, imgWidth, imgHeight);
};

For the detail code I put it at jsfiddle
JSFIDDLE
I want the chart is showing on the image canvas. Thanks!

I'm not sure what exactly do you want to achieve, but in order to start going you have to add animation: false to the chart options, otherwise the chart canvas is added before the animation has even started so there's almost nothing visible.

Also, since in these types of applications it becomes obvious the the chart background is transparent, you may want to paint a (for example white) rectangle in a plugin on the beforeDraw hook, like in this example, see the code in the "plugin" tab

Thanks @kikon for your suggestion, I did your advices but the chart still not appear on the image canvas, any other suggestion ?

Well, I tested the suggestions before writing the messages, I do see a small chart on top of the image - here's a fork of your fiddle - do you see it too? Do you need it somewhere else or something different?

you're right, I tried to my fiddle and it works, but when implemented into my code it still the same that the chart is not appear on the image canvas. Might the version of nextjs, react, and chart.js have an effect ? @kikon

I can't imagine what the issue might be. Don't you get some chart.js-related errors or warnings in console? Can you confirm, by a console.log the the chart constructor gets executed? You may try to make a next.js stackblitz or codesandbox with code similar to that in the fiddle - that might help you clarify the issue without even coming back to stackoverflow, or you can share it with us so we can find out together what happens.
